# may I check/wait updates with useEffect from useSelector?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, use-effect

I have a status data from redux store:

```
const status = useSelector(state => state.appReducer.status);
```

I changing this status in reducer, for example:

```
 case DATA_SUCCESS:
        return update(state, { 
enter code here
            categories: { $set: action.categories },
            status: { $set: 'success'},
            statusText: {$set: 'Categories successfully loaded'}
```

How i tried to handle updates of this state but it not working

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    opener(true)
  },[status]);
```

I SOLVED IT FOR MYSELF:
I putted

```
const status = useSelector(state => state.appReducer.status);
<SomeNestedComponent props={status}/>
```

And In SomeNestedComponent i used useffect:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    // some action here
  },[props.status]);
```

And this useeffect triggering on every change of "status"

Comment: and on re-render you see the `status` value change? I would try to go up the tree of dependencies you have laid out. Check the value in render, then the selector, then the actual state in the reducer after the update.